# The app cannot declare different versions of Google Play services depending on the device configuration

Tags: android, google-play-services

The app cannot declare different versions of Google Play services depending on the device configuration. The following versions were found: [0, 12451000]

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rZp8q.png)

My guess is that the version of `com.google.android.gms.version` is wrong.
But i can not figure out 0 is coming from where.

And i view the manifest via `bundletool.jar` and it looks fine

```
<meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
            android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
```

Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: I was using AGP 7.3.0-alpha07 which failed, tried with 7.2.0-beta04 which passes.

Comment: Are you plagued by this problem (please look at https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/223240936#comment21 comment here too) ?

https://issuetracker.google.com/223240936

Answer (score 3):

I fixed this problem by changing the
`com.android.application` and `com.android.library` version from `7.3.0-alpha 07` to `7.1.2`. This
worked for me without any problems.

Comment: Works for me, thanks! Save my life!